# Adding space between labels and fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, devise, simple-form

In my Rails app, the labels for the fields on the login page are way too close to the fields themselves, making it look cramped. I want to add space between them, but am not sure how.

[image]

I have Rails 4 with simple_form, bootstrap 3, and devise installed.

This is my `app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb` code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4">
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html: {class: "well"}) do |f| %>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Log in</legend>
<%= f.input :email %>
<%= f.input :password %>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div class="field">
           <%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean %>
         </div>

</fieldset>
  <% end -%>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-8">
  <h2>Signing in is easy and secure</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the entire github repo: https://github.com/yamilethmedina/wheels_registration

I've been looking in my `bootstrap.css` file and can't find relevant classes. What do you think I should do next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add your own label with space after the custom label.

```
<%= f.input :email, label: 'Email  ' %>
<%= f.input :password, label: 'Password  ' %>
```

Or you could use tools like `chrome dev tools` to inspect the label element to see what `class` the labels are given and then add some custom css. example `.label-class { margin-right: 10px; }`

Comment: The first method didn't work (on two separate browsers), even after restarting the server. When I inspect the elements, it's called `label.email.optional` for example, which I couldn't find in any of the css files.

Comment: its not in the css files because `simple_form` automatically creates it. You need to add `label.email, label.password { margin-right: 10px; }` in a css file